# Dictionary = Hash?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hash

Is a dictionary basically just a hash table?

Also bonus: In the Ruby code "Hash.new {0}" what is the "{0}" at the end for?

Comment: "Also bonus:" - what do I win? Steak Knives?

Comment: actually, a dictionary has his keys sorted. A ruby hash don't

Comment: @Mauricio: The term "dictionary" does not imply sortedness. Neither python's nor .net's dictionary classes are sorted.

Comment: @sepp2k: Are Ruby's hash's keys sorted in Ruby 1.9?

Comment: In http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103950/what-tag-should-be-used-for-rubys-hashes , I argue that the tag [hash] shouldn't be used for Ruby's hashes, and I ask what tag ought to be used.

Comment: @Andrew: In ruby 1.9 the entries in a hash will keep their insertion order. So no, they aren't sorted, but they are ordered.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The words table, dictionary and map are often used synonymously (in the context of data structures). A hash table/hash map is one kind of table/dictionary/map.

The `{0}` is a block (anonymous function) which ignores its argument and returns the number 0. The block given to `Hash.new` is called to produce a default value when a key is not found in the hash map.

I.e. if I do `h = Hash.new {0}` and then `h["key that does not exist"]`, I get back 0, instead of `nil` (which I'd get without the `{0}`). Note that in this case where the default value is immutable and does not depend on the key, you don't need to use the block form of `Hash.new`, you can just do `Hash.new(0)` to set 0 as the default value.

Answer (score 20):

In Ruby a Hash is a key, value store

```
h = Hash.new
h['one'] = 1
h['one'] #=> 1
h['two'] #=> nil
```

the {0} is a block that will be evaluated if you where to call a Key that did not exist, it's like a default value.

```
h = Hash.new {0}
h['one'] #=> 0
h = Hash.new {|hash,key| "#{key} has Nothing"}
h['one'] #=> "one has Nothing"
```

Answer (score 7):

A dictionary just maps a *key* to a *value*.  There are many ways to achieve this; a hash-table is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

A dictionary is a conceptual interface.  A hash table is a concrete implementation.