# how access specific part of data as an input of AWK

Tags: unix, dictionary, remote-access

Suppose I want to access an online dictionary and need to look for a specific word. I just like to have the specific part of data, which is those related to word and its translation as input of AWK,any idea?

In other words, I just want to have on my machine a margin of data, How can I prevent downloading all the data and hopefully save space and time. Is there any way to do so without downloading all the data to local machine?

This question is related to my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523808/how-to-access-an-online-txt-file-with-awk/35525654#35525654).

Edit 1:

I select dictionary as an example because when you want to look up for a word, it is enough to access a specific part of data and there is no need to process whole of it.

I am not an expert in programming so i was thinking I can modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523808/how-to-access-an-online-txt-file-with-awk/35525654#35525654) to make it work(that is why I add AWK tag again). I dont use any specific OS or tool. this is just a basic idea to see what are the possibilities so I dont know how can I improve the tags.

Comment: I think you are going to need to clarify your requirements.   It may be that `awk` is not the correct tool for the job you're seeking to do.  Google, for example, does not use Awk to process your questions.  Granted, a dictionary is a smaller enterprise than Google, but are you seeking a 'word list' dictionary or a 'meanings of words' dictionary, or a 'history of the meanings and usages of words' dictionary? How many languages?

Comment: what you need is a webservice on "data side" that provides only the short part that you need.

Comment: See edit1 update inside the question

Comment: @Luis Siquot, Do you know if there is any free solution to have a webservice on a server and solve this problem?

Comment: @Ed Morton It is better to make the question more specific and narrow the categories with adding tag not by removing tag. I dont agree with you because if you remove the tag, users searching for awk tag cannot find this question. instead try to add other tags related to curl, wget, etc. And again, I am more interested to solution with AWK

Comment: @Woeistg: yet there is *no question about awk* here. `awk` may be the tool receiving the input, but it doesn't matter what tool receives the input here. Such is the nature of UNIX tools.

Comment: It appears you're looking for something like `wget -qqO- http://example.com/path |grep -wim1 "word"`, which will stop downloading when it finds (and displays) the first instance of "word" (if the dictionary has one word per line, use `-x` instead of `-w`.  If you care about case, remove the `-i`)

Comment: @AdamKatz exactly, that is what i was looking for. tnx. but, it may improve to jumpt to start of "w" character maybe so not to download whole data from "a" to "w". is it possible? I guess not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` cannot download.  You must download the file and pipe it into a command that terminates as soon as it finds a result:

```sh
wget -qqO- http://example.com/path |grep -wim1 "word"
```

`wget -qqO- URL` will have no output other than the content of the given URL, which is placed on standard out so you can then parse it.  `grep -wim1 "word"` will find the first bounded word matching "word" and then terminate.  If you don't need it outputted, you can use `-wiq` instead.  If the dictionary has one word per line (and nothing else), you're better off with `-x` instead of `-w` so that you can match "can" in its entirety rather than "can't" (`'` is a word boundary).  Remove the `-i` if you want to match case.

In the comments, you asked:

> it may improve to jumpt to start of "w" character maybe so not to download whole data from "a" to "w". is it possible? I guess not

Some programs can "resume" downloads and you may be able to play with that, but you'd have to guess where to start.  This would be a lot of work and you might seek too far and therefore fail to get a match.

If you are querying this dictionary more than once, I'd recommend downloading it and saving it so you can query it locally.  Even [the largest dictionary I know of](http://blog.sebastien.raveau.name/2009/03/cracking-passwords-with-wikipedia.html) is only 213MB (compressed, search with `zgrep`), though I am assuming you're talking about a traditional word list rather than a [hash table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719272/dictionary-hash/4719292#4719292) or other arbitrary data form.  Of course, anything longer would take such a long time to download that you'd only want to do it once.

If you really don't want to store it locally, you should probably consider a database rather than a flat file.

Comment: What do you think about this approach: Only for the first time, read the dictionary and make a local index.By local infex,I mean a collection of possitions of letters in online alphabet, for example 'w' line 10000). Is it possible to modify the command you sent amd start to search from position 10000?

Comment: If you want a "real" language that has proper seeking within a file, that would work well.  Otherwise, I'd recommend splitting the file by letter so you can use `grep`.  (You could still seek with `tail`, but it's ugly.)